# Should I undelete my question that deleted due "RemoveAbandonedQuestions"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Question:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/491289/how-to-prevent-squashfs-cache-decompressed-data-and-only-keep-compressed-data-in

Timeline:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/491289/timeline

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion would be to follow the existing StackExchange advice, link to via the [deleted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) link on your question, which describes the conditions under which questions are roomba'd. That page further says:

> If you believe your question can still be answered (by you or anyone else), see: [What should I do if I find the answer to an old question of mine that was automatically deleted as abandoned?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309526/what-should-i-do-if-i-find-the-answer-to-an-old-question-of-mine-that-was-automa/310266#310266)

which points to a couple answers that should be helpful. The high points to me are [Monica's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/309533/307535):

> Notice that I talked about fixing the problems that led to the deletion. If your question was deleted as abandoned, then not only was it unanswered but it also wasn't upvoted. Maybe that's because it's a super-obscure topic and few people even read it -- or maybe it means there is room for improvement in the question. The best course of action, then, is to edit to improve it and then request undeletion from users with the undelete privilege. On the sites I frequent, this is usually done via a request on meta.

and [Shog9's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310266/307535):

> Monica's advice on fixing the question is solid - anything you can do to correct whatever caused it to not get the necessary attention the first time around is worth doing.
>
> In particular, take this opportunity to add what you've learned in the time since you first asked.
>
> But then... Just re-ask the question.

My personal opinion would be to ask it anew, including whatever you've tried or learned in the year-plus interim.